# Views,Entity,Cannot deduce a primary key

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I made a view so the back hand of my website is more coherent. Then i tried to map it to my entity schema.

I had the message :

> No primary key defined, could not deduce a primary key, table excluded

So i made one ! I made sure it was something unique by combining 3 columns that cannot be identical when combined. And i called that new column "id".

Entity dosen't seems to agree with the unique aspect of my "id" because the error message wont go away and i can't import my view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i had to use the sql function ISNULL(id,) on my "id" clolumn, making it a not null value so Entity understand that it could NEVER be null and therefore, detecting it as a potential primary key

Comment: this is not what is EF's job. "id" should be the key after code first conventions, if not, you should declare it as key using data annotations or fluent API. However, when you have to use sql, this would suggest a DB first approach. There, EVERY table has to have a NOT NULL PK column combination, so if something is wrong in the metadata, EF can expect the model to be not correct (it would not be able to re-create the table using the metadata) and exclude it.

Comment: I use db first approach yes, but you see, usualy i somehow end up with unique fields (primary keys) inside my views. In this case i don't even have to specify witch column is a potential primary key, Entity does that job for me and decide witch combination of field would represente the best primary key in the view, but this time i did not had any (not null) unique values, so i created one and specified it could not be null... i know it's weird but it worked

Comment: EF will know any property named "Id" or TypeName(+'_')+"Id" is the PK of the to be created property, if this is not the case you'll have to specify it, I do not think it will recognize any other combination, as it will not know which properties are a unique identifier for all rows. If you go code first, you can take any combination of not nullable properties (which can be mapped to single columns) and specify those as key using data annotation/fluent api.

Comment: I verified, that doesn't apply to DB first